# How can I fix the code to fade a button & change a button blue on click?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I am trying to create a javascript event where on click of `button2` it changes the box to the color blue. And on click of `button3` it fades the box.

I have two other actions that cause the `button1` to grow and `button4` resets it, but I cannot get the other two to work. What do I need to fix in the code?

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
})

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundcolor = "blue";
});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("box").fadeOut();
});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementById("box").style.height = "100px";
});
```

Comment: I do not think I posted the code correctly but it's my first post...

Comment: Ok the code is fixed I know someone is smarter than me who can help! Thanks

Comment: Ok I didn't know style attributes were case sensitive. Thanks for the input and help getting this code working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding button 2, style attributes are case sensitive, you're looking for `backgroundColor`:

```
document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Regarding button 3, there is no native javascript `fadeOut()` function, I'm assuming you're trying to use the jQuery function of the same name. To do so, you need to ensure you're including jQuery and select the element with a jQuery selector:

```
$('#box').fadeOut();
```

See the below snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
})

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click",function(){
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click",function(){
  $('#box').fadeOut();
});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.getElementById("box").style.height = "100px";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3">Button 3</button>
<button id="button4">Button 4</button>

<div id="box" style="height: 50px; width: 300px; background-color: #ff0000; margin-top: 10px;">
 &nbsp;
</div>
```